# What CMS can I use with react native?

Tags: android, iphone, react-native, mobile, content-management-system

I’m developing a react native mobile app, I’m new with this. The app needs to have a way for a person to change something (like the logo or title) of the app on specific occasions. I was thinking on integrating with a CMS

how can I go about this? what CMS can I use that has a good integration with react native mobile apps?

I haven’t worked with a CMS before, and I’m new with react native’s

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about programming and will probably lead to opinion based answers .. both of these options are not acceptable here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned about what have you tried doing when integrating React native with any CMS I would just like to help you in order to give you some direction.

> how can I go about this? what CMS can I use that has a good
> integration with react native mobile apps?

First, you need to understand. Why do you need a CMS and what are the advantages of using a CMS ? With regards to React native, you can integrate it with any known CMS solution that exists.

If in case you plan to use Drupal, then please have a look at this [link](https://dropsolid.io/knowledge-hub/drupal-8-and-react-native). Basically, all CMS solutions have something called as "Headless" mode that allow to expose RESTful API's to the frontend so that it can consume the data from CMS and display.

Hope that helps.